# How to edit image and update in laravel

Tags: laravel-5.8

I have a table called Services, now this table has the following -

-id
-title
-body
-image
-slug
-timestamps

And in administrator, services page I created for Add, Edit, Delete it.

My problem is `edit` and `update` a image. A strange problem is that, when I change the of `image` to `aaaaa` field in the service table (database), Nothing happens. should happen. because I changed rename of `image` to `aaaaa`.

web.php

```
Route::resource('services', 'ServiceController');
```

ServiceController.php

```
public function edit(Service $service)
{
    return view('Admin.services.edit', compact('service'));
}

public function update(Request $request, Service $service)
{
    $service->title = $request->title;
    $service->body = $request->body;

    if($request->has('image')) {
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
        $image->move(public_path('images/services'), $filename);
        $service->image = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
    }

    $service->update();

    return redirect()->route('services.index');
}
```

edit.blade.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="{{ route('services.update', $service->id) }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ method_field('PATCH') }}
    @include('Admin.layouts.errors')
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">عنوان</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="عنوان" value="{{ $service->title ? : old('title') }}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="body">متن</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="10" id="body" name="body" placeholder="متن">{{ $service->body ? : old('body') }}</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="images">تصویر</label>
        <div class="custom-file">
            <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="images" name="images">
            <label class="custom-file-label" for="images">تصویر محصول</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ذخیره</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Service.php

```
protected $fillable = [
    'title',
    'body',
    'image',
    'slug',
];
```

I even changed the controller in the `update` method as follows, nothing happened.

```
$service->save();
```

Comment: When I open `ServiceController` and write `dd(request->image);` show `null` for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the html you have:

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="images" name="images">
```

and in Controller: $request->file('image').

Replace

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="images" name="images">
```

with

```
<input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="images" name="image">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think one of efficient way to edit image in laravel.
add this at top of the controller

```
use File;
```

First of get your bannerId in a variable

```
$bannerId = $request->banner_id;
```

get object of that id by find ().

```
  $bannerData = FrontEndBanner::find($bannerId);
```

check if file exist and check if file already exist then delete that file else same name will inserted in imageName variable

```
if ($request->hasFile('banner_image')){
    $image_path = public_path("/uploads/resource/".$bannerData->banner_name);
    if (File::exists($image_path)) {
        File::delete($image_path);
    }
    $bannerImage = $request->file('banner_image');
    $imgName = $bannerImage->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/resource/');
    $bannerImage->move($destinationPath, $imgName);
  } else {
    $imgName = $bannerData->banner_name;
  }

  $bannerData->title = $request->banner_title;
  $bannerData->banner_name = $imgName;
  $bannerData->save();
```

If anyone have issue then comment